# Core Data Migration Very Slow

Tags: core-data, migration

I'm trying to perform a core data migration and everything is working fine, except that the migration itself takes over 10 seconds. I'm using an xcmappingmodel to map between my two model versions which works fine, except for the length of time it takes.

In the code below, there's a 10 second (or longer!) pause between the "Beginning migration" and "Finished migration" logs. Has anyone encountered such a slow migration before?

I know that all of the data is replicated and transferred to the new store during the migration, but I'm not dealing with a *huge* dataset, maybe 20 entities with 3,000 records, so I can't imagine it'd take *that* long.

I'd really appreciate any help - thanks!

Michael

```
NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption,
[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption, nil];

NSLog(@"Beginning migration");

if (![persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:options error:&error])
{
    NSLog(@"Auto migration failed, error %@, %@", error, error.userInfo);
    abort();
}   

NSLog(@"Finished migration");
```

Comment: The truth is it really can take much time. Even saving context after inserting few thousand rows can take 10+ seconds. That's why you save in batches if you have that many rows.

Comment: Thanks svena. I've added a workaround where I bring up a UIAlertView with a UIActivityIndicator then perform the migration.